# How to show scrollbar in contenteditable div with max-height?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, contenteditable

I have a `div` with the `contenteditable` tag set to `true`.
Also, I've added `width`, `height`, etc. using CSS.

Then this is the result:

```css
#stringinput {
    min-width: 20em;
    min-height: 1.4em;
    max-width: 40em;
    max-height: 10em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: left;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="stringinput" spellcheck="false"></div>
```

It works fine, but when you are typing and you reach the `max-height` limit, the div expands downwards, but the border stays where it should be.

So, I want a scrollbar to appear when someone reaches the `max-height` limit, so that the div doesn't expand any further downwards. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Insert `overflow-y: auto;` Like This:

```
#stringinput {
    overflow-y: auto;
   //More code
}
```

**Full Code:**

```css
#stringinput {
    min-width: 20em;
    min-height: 1.4em;
    max-width: 40em;
    max-height: 10em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: left;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="stringinput" spellcheck="false">
Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.Sample Text.
</div>
```

The `overflow-y: auto` property auto-enables the scrollbar when the `max-height` (y-axis) limit is reached.

Comment: Exactly! I didn't know there was such a simple solution to this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

your code is alright just put overflow-x : hidden in the css it will work

```css
#stringinput {
    min-width: 20em;
    min-height: 1.4em;
    max-width: 40em;
    max-height: 10em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: left;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow-x : hidden;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="stringinput" spellcheck="false"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the job as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#stringinput {
    min-width: 20em;
    height: 2.4em;
    max-width: 40em;
    overflow: scroll;
    max-height: 10em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: left;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="stringinput" spellcheck="false"></div>
```

In order to enable the scroll bar.
You need to set your height and defines the overflow behaviour that you want (here scrollable).

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I was looking for. Now, the scrollbar is also visible when no text is entered, or the `max-height` limit isn't reached.

Comment: Oh. Which browser are you using ? Not happening on Google chrome / Mac Osx. Interesting !

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome / Windows 10, if I run the snippet I see a div with disabled scrollbars on the x-axis and y-axis.. strange?